# Why Asp.Net Core QueryHelpers don't encode comma (,) symbol?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, encoding, urlencode

Why Asp.Net Core QueryHelpers don't encode comma (,) symbol?

This [link1](http://web.archive.org/web/20131212154213/http://urldecoderonline.com/url-allowed-characters.htm) [link2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding#Reserved_characters) says comma(,) symbol should be encoded

```
QueryHelpers.AddQueryString(url, queryString);
```

The above line of returns the below output without encoding comma(,) in the state parameter.

"https://bank.com?client_id=App1&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Fgoogle.com&state=Alice,Bob,Cherry"

Comment: The linked page is wrong. The comma is perfectly valid and safe without being encoded. It has no special purpose in URL query strings.

Comment: @madreflection, how about link2 mentioning?

Comment: Your second link says that "a URI scheme says that it is necessary to use that character for some *other purpose*" but `QueryHelpers` is being used for a URI scheme (http[s]) that doesn't use that character for a special purpose.

Comment: The question is fine (that's I don't vote it down) but it should be close since is not reproducible because the referenced documentation is wrong and/or obsolete, as @madreflection said.

Comment: That's right :) BTW, in my experience is not good idea 1) Work with GET for this 2) Pass an array splitted by comma in any case, GET or POST. I should suggest work with POST and JSON

Comment: if you look at some of the online encoding tools like https://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/dencoder/ it even encodes (,). If my business requirement says (,) in url query string should be encoded how to go about it, with custom logic? without using inbuilt "QueryHelpers" class?

Comment: That's fine that they do and there's nothing wrong about doing that, but not doing it for the comma is not wrong, so the expectation that it gets encoded is incorrect.

Comment: Now let's address the idiocy that a *business requirement* includes technical specifications. ***That*** is wrong. All kinds of wrong.

Comment: This is where you push back and say "This business requirement overreaches its purview and needs to be removed."

Comment: I talk from my tech experience, but as Product Owner, I don't give tech suggestions if I'm not required, so something is wrong here. In any case that's why mine was a suggestion. Take in consideration that is not a pattern by Microsoft MVC and URL has some limitations abouth lenght. Also using GET without routing in 2021 is a bit obsolete as architecture pattern.

Answer (score 0):

Answer:

> The referenced document is wrong as @madreflection said. The C#
> function works fine.

Back to the basics:

Everything on the network pattern that specify a rule is made by its respective RFC

In this case we have to look at: [RFC 3986](http://%20https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc3986.txt) about  `URI Generic Syntax`

> URI producing applications    often use the reserved characters
> allowed in a segment to delimit    scheme-specific or
> dereference-handler-specific subcomponents.  For    example, the
> semicolon (";") and equals ("=") reserved characters are    often used
> to delimit parameters and parameter values applicable to    that
> segment.  The comma (",") reserved character is often used for
> similar purposes.  For example, one URI producer might use a segment
> such as "name;v=1.1" to indicate a reference to version 1.1 of
> "name", whereas another might use a segment such as "name,1.1" to
> indicate the same.  Parameter types may be defined by scheme-specific
> semantics, but in most cases the syntax of a parameter is specific to
> the implementation of the URI's dereferencing algorithm.

So two things are clear here:

- Don't need of encoding.
- Suggested as reserved by arch for syntaxis problem, not string splitter separator.

You can use this tool: https://0mg.github.io/tools/uri/
to ensure your link is valid from that RFC

Comment: To clarify this answer, when I said the linked page was wrong, I was referring to the first link, which was the only link provided at the time. The second link. added in response, contains accurate information, but OP didn't interpret the information correctly, which also appears to be the basis of incorrect information on the first link.

Comment: @madreflection that's right, sorry for my "abbreviation" and thanks to clarify my answer