# QueryBuilder is not encoding `@` in query parameters, anyway to force it?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, query-builder

I have a custom web service that I query and provide an email (`MyUser@MyDomain.com`) and ad account (`MyDomain\\MyUser`) as arguments using `QueryBuilder`, but when I do `.ToQueryString()`, the `@` symbol is not encoded?

Is there a way to get a properly encoded string or a reason it's not encoding?

```
QueryBuilder qb = new QueryBuilder();
qb.Add("adAccount", "MyDomain\\MyUser");
qb.Add("email", "MyUser@MyDomain.com");

var queryString = qb.ToQueryString();
```

My code above returns (`@`):

> `?adAccount=MyDomain%5CMyUser&email=MyUser@MyDomain.com`

But I would expect (`%40`):

> `?adAccount=MyDomain%5CMyUser&email=MyUser%40MyDomain.com`

Comment: No, that just says the `@` symbol needs to be encoded, which I agree. I'm wondering why `QueryBuilder` is not correctly encoding it?

Comment: I see the text "Instead of percent-encoding it, you may use @ directly in the HTTP URI path." in the answer.

Comment: @gunr2171 you're ignoring the question. The question is, why isn't `QueryBuilder` encoding it when it encodes other symbols (such as "\")

Comment: Certain symbols don't need to be encoded when they're in the query string, but do need to be encoded elsewhere. `QueryBuilder` specifically deals with the query string, where `@` does not need to be encoded because it is not defined by the URI scheme as having a special purpose in that context.

Comment: @madreflection I see. Is there a way to tell `QueryBuilder` to encode it? Or is there a better query string builder? It seems unusual it's not encoding reserved characters.

Comment: Why bother? It doesn't need to be encoded.

Comment: @madreflection the custom WCF API needs it encoded. It's a legacy system that does some old method of URL decode and it's failing with the `@` symbol.

Comment: Then it's functionally broken.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70293317/why-asp-net-core-queryhelpers-dont-encode-comma-symbol

Comment: @madreflection It's not broken. It's a legacy (Microsoft ERP) system that conforms to the standards at the time and is no longer maintained. It requires the `@` symbol be encoded and that's what I'm trying to accomplish using `QueryBuilder` or some other technology.

Comment: It *is* broken because a proper parser should know that it's not necessary in that context. It doesn't implement the specification properly. Write your own encoder.

Comment: What you're talking about is not related to the question. The problem is getting `QueryBuilder` (or a similar technology) to encode `@` because a legacy system (Microsoft Dynamics AX 2012) requires it.  Pointing out _AX 2012 should take the @ symbol_ may be true, but it's not something I can change unfortunately. More relevant is just because a URI _can_ handle an `@` symbol, that doesn't mean if a system only accepts it encoded it's incorrect. The other answers in your link agree that it should be encoded in this use.

Comment: `QueryBuilder` produces minimally encoded, compliant output for a query string. That's its purpose. It doesn't exceed that purpose by providing an option to encode characters that don't need to be encoded in a quey string. This is me giving you the knowledge that the other system's expectations are broken and `QueryBuilder` is not going to give you the output you desire. Maybe you can find a different object that fulfils your needs; I don't know of any. Recommendations for libraries are off-topic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

QueryBuilder's source code is located [here](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/main/src/Http/Http.Extensions/src/QueryBuilder.cs) - it's not a complicated class, basically just a `List<KeyValuePair<string,string>>` that performs an UrlEncode on the key/values when it's being `ToString`'d. It's not sealed and the `ToString` is overridable so you can create your own version that will work anywhere a QueryBuilder is expected:

```
class QueryBuilderEx : QueryBuilder
{
    public override string ToString()
    {
        return base.ToString().Replace("@", "%40");
    }
}
```

If you only want to edit the value, and leave the key alone it's a bit more of a nuisance, because you need to reimplement the ToString in the style of the original, but the `_params` list in which the pairs are stored is private so not accessible to your subclass. You can however, have your QueryBuilder enumerate itself:

```
class QueryBuilderEx : QueryBuilder
{
    public override string ToString()
    {
        var builder = new StringBuilder();
        bool first = true;
        foreach(var pair in this)
        {
            builder.Append(first ? '?' : '&');
            first = false;
            builder.Append(UrlEncoder.Default.Encode(pair.Key));
            builder.Append('=');
            builder.Append(UrlEncoder.Default.Encode(pair.Value).Replace("@", "%40"));
        }

        return builder.ToString();
    }
}
```

Comment: Ah the source code makes it much easier to understand! Overriding is just what I was exploring. I believe this means I need to replace `QueryBuilder` with `QueryBuilderEx` everywhere I'm using it though?

Comment: If you press `Ctrl-H` Visual Studio can help you out with that..

Comment: beautiful and elegant!